# Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I finally managed to get the Thumbnail Grid With Expanding Preview from codrops (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/) to work well on my new Bootstrap website layout that I have been working on. However once I clicked on an image in it will expand, but once I click on the expansion or the close button it will not return to the original grid. I took a screenshot to show what it looks like.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/eajFH.jpg]

Comment: post a fiddle please

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nn6zke3a/